# How to auto-run db:migrate after docker app is deployed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, docker, heroku, docker-compose

I specified `rails db:setup` `rails db:migrate` in my entrypoint.sh file. It runs locally, but heroku says "relation todos does not exist".

I then only left `rails db:migrate` since I do not have permissions to run `rails db:setup` on heroku, but the problem persists.

Is there any way to automatically run migrations on heroku in docker app?

Comment: Are you specifying this in the `heroku.yml` configuration file listed here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/build-docker-images-heroku-yml?

Comment: Yes, specifying release phase in `heroku.yml` solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying this in the heroku.yml configuration file listed here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/build-docker-images-heroku-yml

Fixed their problem.